# Magento 2: How to set up Paypal Payflow Pro Sandbox?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, paypal-payflow-pro, sandbox-mode

Can someone provide clear instructions on how to set up Magento 2 to work with a Paypal PayflowPro Sandbox?

I feel like I've tried every possible combination of user/vendor/merchant id/account id/sub account id/ password and still am getting a 'User authentication failed' error.

My basic set up, per Paypals [documentation](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-set-up-payflow-pro-with-paypal-sandbox-ts1961): I have a sandbox environment set up with a sandbox sub account (Business) with a test@myco.com email address, I have a Manager.paypal.com account set up and have followed the instructions to add the test@myco.com email to the 'Sandbox Seller' field.

In Magento, I have the following fields, per the Magento [documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-payflow-pro.html):

```
Email Associated with your PayPal Merchant Account
Partner:    Your PayPal Partner ID
User:   The ID of an additional user who is set up on your PayPal account
Vendor: Your PayPal user login name
Password: PW that is associated with your PayPal account.
```

Which Paypal account information goes with which Magento field?

Does the 'User' field above who is 'set up on your Paypal account' reflect the sandbox environment user? or do I need to create an additional user in the manager.paypal.com account?

Does the Password field require the password from the manager account, or the test@myco.com account? Is the User field the *email address* of test@myco.com, or the Paypal provided *Account ID*?

Answer (score 1):

The terminology is extremely confusing. This is what works for me:

```
Email: Email associated with your Merchant Account
Partner: PayPal
User: Your manager.paypal.com login username
Vendor: Your mmanager.paypal.com login username
Password: Your manager.paypal.com password
```

Also, set Test Mode to "Yes" in the Magento config to ensure posts to Payflow Pro hit the sandbox URL rather than the live payment URL.